# Кастомный адаптер для AutoCompleteTextView, для которого не важен порядок слов

Tags: android, adapter, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

Допустим, вот один из элементов `AutoCompleteTextView` :  `слово, словцо, словечко`

Хочу, чтобы этот элемент отображался при вводе `слово, словечко`

Единственный кастомный адаптер, который я нашёл для `AutoCompleteTextView`, - это  адаптер, фильтрующий по принципу `contains`, вместо стандартного `StartsWith`, но он здесь ни к селу ни к городу.

Comment: Не совсем понятно что имеется в виду. AutoCompleteTextView это обычный EditText с подсказками. Подсказки по сути это ScrollView. 

Кастомные адаптеры не ищут. Их берут и пишут. Берется BaseAdapter и расширяется с implement Filterable в котором и фильтруется имеющийся список подсказок.

Comment: @ШуткоАлександр , ну я с удовольствием написал бы его себе, если б навыки позволяли. Но покуда я ламер, спрашиваю вот других, если завалялся у кого-нибудь, пусть кинет.

Comment: Врятли у кого-то завалялся. Слишком специфично. Кроме того описание совсем неоднозначно. Понять как именно фильтруются значения нереально. Надо чтобы показывались те значения у которых совпало 2 слова из трех ? Или совпадение любого слова ? Или все три но в любом порядке ? Слова разделены запятыми ? пользователь тоже разделять будет слова запятыми ?

Comment: @ШуткоАлександр яж в названии написал "Кастомный адаптер для AutoCompleteTextView, **для которого не важен порядок слов**"

Comment: @ШуткоАлександр например, при вводе `словцо, словечко` стандартный адаптер покажет нужный результат, т.е. он понимает, что пробел - это начало нового слова, осталось дать ему понять, что порядок этих слов может быть каким угодно.

Comment: @ШуткоАлександр по-моему, достаточно полезная фича, которая много где может пригодиться.